# sql not inserting record

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to insert a record into my database.  here is my php code for doing that:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO answers(answer)
        VALUES('answer')");
        if(mysql_affected_rows() > 0) {
            echo "Reply successful!";
        } else {
            echo "We were not able to add your reply.";
            exit();
        }
```

i made sure that i am connected to my db.  i tried this on another page where i knew my sql would run, and it still didn't insert the record...

Comment: Are you getting an error? If so, what is it? You can use mysql_error() to see exactly what is wrong.

Comment: Please take a few minutes to read this [meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). It will be beneficial to you, as I'm pretty sure if you don't start doing so, people will stop trying to help you pretty soon. Thanks. :)

Comment: Does your table contains an auto increment field (i.e ID)?><br>
If yes take a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add

`echo mysql_error();`

to see the problem

Comment: i get a "Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'"

Answer (score 1):

Try passing `$answer` instead of `answer`. Also you should read up on [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection).